# P/Invoke method broken just by updating from .Net 4.5 to .Net 4.5.1

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, .net-4.5

I have a P/Invoke call in my application which communicates with an external piece of hardware via an API (a .dll file) written in C++

This method worked perfectly untill I installed the latest .Net 4.5.1, and without making any code changes it now throws an exception: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'"

Is there anything I should check to make my app compatible with .Net 4.5.1? Rolling back to a previous framework is the only way I have found to make it work!

```
[DllImport("TestAPI", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
internal static extern bool OMBOpen(int VID, int PID, int CID,
   StringBuilder description,
   int bufferSize);
```

The native declaration of the method in C++

```
TESTAPI_API 
bool OMBOpen(int VID,int PID,int IID,char* buffer,int bufferSize);
```

---

EDIT:

In the end the problem turned out not to be with the above method call itself at all, but with marshalling data from a pointer to a data structure (See accepted answer), which was elsewhere in the code as David Heffernan wiseley suspected.

Comment: try "TestAPI.dll" instead of "TestAPI"

Comment: @thefiloe No joy but thanks..

Comment: can you show the native declaration of the function?

Comment: @thefiloe edited to include this!

Comment: Do you have multiple `TestAPI.dll` files? Could it be referencing a different version? Could try different definition combinations of the [DllImport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4byd5y4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Seems unlikely that the code in the question causes that error. An SSCCE?

Comment: Can you add the stack trace for the exception (at least the calls near the actual throw until it gets back up into your code) to your posting?

Comment: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'"`

This is not a runtime error but a compiler error message.

Comment: I am from Microsoft .NET Framework team. Could you send me detailed repro code that works on .NET4.5 but does not work on .NET 4.5.1, I would like to investigate. send it on netfx45compat at Microsoft com Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Varun I have sent you a sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'" is thrown when attempting to assign the result of a void method to a variable. While this is normally a compiler error, if it's seen during execution then it usually occurred as a result of dynamic invocation of a method (e.g. using the dynamic keyword or using a dynamic language like IronPython).

.NET 4.5.1 introduced a overloads for `Marshal.SizeOf` and `Marshal.PtrToStructure` and dynamic method invocation may pick the new overload under certain circumstances. See Microsoft [KB2909958](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2909958). The above exception wouldn't be coming from the P/Invoke itself, but from the subsequent marshaling operations.

The easiest solution to these kinds of issues is to just introduce a cast within the call to ensure that the correct method is resolved.

```cs
#Code from 4.5
dynamic dynamicVar = ...
object boxedStruct = Marshal.PtrToStructure(myPtr, dynamicVar.GetType());
// Above resolves to 'object Marshal.PtrToStructure(IntPtr, Type)' in 4.5
// and resolves to 'void Marshal.PtrToStructure<T>(IntPtr, T)' in 4.5.1
int size = Marshal.SizeOf(dynamicVar.GetType());
// Above resolves to 'object Marshal.SizeOf(Type)' in 4.5
// and resolves to 'void Marshal.SizeOf<T>(T)' in 4.5.1

#Fixed for 4.5.1
dynamic dynamicVar = ...
object boxedStruct = Marshal.PtrToStructure(myPtr, (Type)dynamicVar.GetType());
// Adding the cast forces the code to resolve to
// 'object Marshal.PtrToStructure(IntPtr, Type)'
int size = Marshal.SizeOf((Type)dynamicVar.GetType());
// Adding the cast forces the code to resolve to
// 'int Marshal.SizeOf(Type)'
```

Comment: Solved my problem, and very pleased .Net authors picked this thread up so quickly!

Comment: @Xavier Are you saying that the actual error is in code that calls `PtrToStructure` and `SizeOf`, and that code is in Alex's app and not in the question? I'm just trying to understand.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Yes. That's correct. The code is elsewhere in the app and is related to marshaling to/from P/Invoke calls.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that I can find wrong with the code in the question is the return value. By default the marshaller will assume the native code is returning a 4 byte `BOOL`. You should write the pinvoke like this:

```
[DllImport(...)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
internal static extern bool OMBOpen(...);
```

However, I don't see how that could lead to the error that you report. I rather suspect that the actual problem lies in code that is not in the question.

**References:**

1. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2008/10/14/pinvoke-and-bool-or-should-i-say-bool.aspx
2. http://www.greengingerwine.com/index.php/2011/08/always-marshal-bool-return-types-when-using-pinvoke/
3. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182206.aspx